# How to filter a jcombobox? java

Tags: java, jcombobox

I have a string list of values that populate a jcombobox. As the user starts typing i want to start filter the results. Could someone tell me a suitable approach to achieve this?

Initially i was thinking of having a '`master`' and '`slave`' array, where i would copy the filtered results into the `slave` and display whatever is within slave array. The issue with this is that i'm copying the data twice... so what other ways could i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JComboBox Filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578710/jcombobox-filter)

Comment: You may find that this might not quite work the way you want it to. As you remove items from the list, my experience has being that the pop up won't resize :P

Comment: The other question you have linked implies to use a library. I want to try and code my own, for my own development. I'm asking for ways to do this ..

Comment: @RoryLester But [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) is a [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) component. Swing is built on top of [java.awt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) if that is what you meant. Whatever it is, you should retag your question properly.