# Setting a tooltip for a value from JComboBox's Items as CellEditor in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip, jcombobox

I would like to set a tooltip value for the values in a custom combo box. Basically, my combobox contains a list of initials of people - when they hover over i want it to display the fullname of the person. My combo box is basically a cell/column of a JTable that has its own TableCellRenderer and DefaultCellEditor. The list is a JList (inner class within the model) - iv tried setting the 'setToolTipText' method directly but that doesnt seem to work.

Here is the code:

*Code within the JTable: *

```
public void setupUserCombo(Container container){
      TableColumn col = getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
      Set<ComboUser> values = new LinkedHashSet<ComboUser>();

      ComboUser comboUser = new ComboUser(new User("Test User"));
      values.add(comboUser);

      col.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor((ComboUser[])values.toArray(new ComboUser[0])));
      col.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer((ComboUser[])values.toArray(new ComboUser[0])));
      repaint();
}

public class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyComboBoxRenderer(ComboUser[] items) {
        super(items);
        repaint();
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value != null){
            System.out.println("Setting tooltip");
            ((ComboUser)value).setToolTipText("TESTING!!");
        }
        setSelectedItem(value);

        return this;
    }
}

public class MyComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyComboBoxEditor(ComboUser[] items) {
        super(new JComboBox(items));
    }
}
```

*Subclass within the model: *

```
public class ComboUser extends JLabel{

    private User user;

    public ComboUser(User user){
        if (user != null){
            this.user = user;
        } else {
            this.user = new User("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return user.getInitials();
    }
```

Comment: a) never-ever add JSomething to the data realm (a comboUser certainly doesn't fulfill a is-a relation to a JLabel) b) never-ever implement any classes just for sake of overriding toString for view reasons (that's what renderers are for) c) don't subclass if you can reach the same by configuring the available class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want tooltips in the editing combobox, you'll have to so in a custom renderer of that combobox. Below is a short example:

```
// some data
User[] users = new User[] { 
        new User("Clara Zetkin", "CZ"),
        new User("Rosa Luxemburg", "RL"),
        new User("Susan Sontag", "SS"),
};
// the renderer for use in the editor
ListCellRenderer comboRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
            Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof User) {
            setToolTipText(((User) value).getName());
            value = ((User) value).getInitials();
        } else {
            setToolTipText(null);
        }
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
                cellHasFocus);
    }

};
JComboBox editingCombo = new JComboBox(users);
editingCombo.setRenderer(comboRenderer);

JTable table = new JTable(3, 2);
// set up the editor for the first column
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(editingCombo));
// the renderer to use in the table
TableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof User) {
            setToolTipText(((User) value).getInitials());
            value = ((User) value).getName();
        } else {
            setToolTipText(null);
        }
        super.setValue(value);
    }

};
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

Comment: +1 for basic stuff, please why not `BasicComboBoxRenderer` (`Editable`/`Non_Editable` `JComboBox`)

Comment: @mKorbel - don't understand what you mean ;-) Shooting into the wild: never-ever use a plaf class if you can achieve your goal without.

Comment: aaach, true, one side of coin there are implemented everything, 2nd true is that is possible easiest, confortable and simpler :-)

Comment: @Klepatra - this works almost perfectly so thanks for that! The only problem is that the JCombo box doesnt look like it exists when it first loads the table (i.e. there is no drop down arrow, it just looks like a normal cell in the table). Its only when i click on the seemingly empty cell that the dropdown box appears. Any idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

[see JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip), test code examples, for example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;

public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        final JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        initColumnSizes(table);
        setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset to default");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    table.getModel().setValueAt("None of the above", i, 2);
                }
            }
        });
        add(resetButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void initColumnSizes(JTable table) {
        MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel) table.getModel();
        TableColumn column = null;
        Component comp = null;
        int headerWidth = 0;
        int cellWidth = 0;
        Object[] longValues = model.longValues;
        TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            comp = headerRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(null, column.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
            headerWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            comp = table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(i)).getTableCellRendererComponent(table, longValues[i], false, false, 0, i);
            cellWidth = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
            column.setPreferredWidth(Math.max(headerWidth, cellWidth));
        }
    }

    private void setUpSportColumn(JTable table, TableColumn sportColumn) {
        ArrayList<String> listSomeString = new ArrayList<String>();
        listSomeString.add("Snowboarding");
        listSomeString.add("Rowing");
        listSomeString.add("Knitting");
        listSomeString.add("Speed reading");
        listSomeString.add("Pool");
        listSomeString.add("None of the above");
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem(new Item(1, "-"));
        comboBox.addItem(new Item(2, "Snowboarding"));
        comboBox.addItem(new Item(3, "Rowing"));
        comboBox.addItem(new Item(4, "Knitting"));
        comboBox.addItem(new Item(5, "Speed reading"));
        comboBox.addItem(new Item(6, "Pool"));
        comboBox.addItem(new Item(7, "None of the above"));
        comboBox.setMaximumRowCount(3);
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                Item item = (Item) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(item.getId() + " : " + item.getDescription());
            }
        });
        //comboBox.setRenderer(new ItemRenderer());
        sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
        sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    class ItemRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value != null) {
                Item item = (Item) value;
                setText(item.getDescription().toUpperCase());
            }
            if (index == -1) {
                Item item = (Item) value;
                setText("" + item.getId());
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    class Item {

        private int id;
        private String description;

        public Item(int id, String description) {
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description;
        }
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {{"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), false},
            {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), true}, {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), false},
            {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), true}, {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), false}};
        public final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy", "None of the above", new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            if (col < 2) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            System.out.println("New value of data: " + getValueAt(row, col));
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure this is what im looking for - this just sets the tooltip for the whole combobox. I would like it to be set for each cell within the combobox

Comment: are you meaning tooltip for JComboBox Items (as CellEditor in JTable) or to display ToolTip from Renderer

Comment: I've been trying to set it from the renderer but thats not working. Basically when they click on the drop down list it as a some values in the list - when they hover over it should display the tooltip associated with that value. Is that possible?

Comment: is possible in the code example is implemented BasicComboBoxRenderer, but then to use Vector for ComboBoxModel instead of arrays of Items, some code examples about ToolTip and JComboBox drop down must be on this forum, notice I'm would be going this way, could be required some additional code for notifying JComboBox as CellEditor, no idea, never tried

Comment: im not sure i follow, could you give an example maybe?

Comment: gentle reminder: example code in answers should be SSCCE, too ;-)