# JComboBox search list

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox, netbeans-8

I w'd like make a `JComboBox` that contents could be searchable.
I tried `AutoCompleteDecorator, GlazedLists, SwingLabs, JIDE, Laf-Widget`, but all of the cannot search by second keyword.
For example, in this code possible search by 1st letter and this content includes just one word.

```
this.comboBox = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "Ester", "Jordi", "Jordina", "Jorge", "Sergi" });
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(this.comboBox);
```

If `JComboBox` content consists 2 or 3 words, for example: "Ester Jordi" or "Jorge Sergi", in this case if I enter "Sergi", `JComboBox`don't show nothing, because it can recognize by 1st word.
I w'd like to ask is there have any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I found this FilterComboBox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368856/jcombobox-filter-in-java-look-and-feel-independent  . My JFrame includes many ComboBoxes with long line data, for quick search I need a SuggestField as Google. Problem is I don't know how to adopt this code to my JFrame.

Comment: @Marius Žilėnas: I am sorry for long delay. I followed to your suggestion, but still I couldn't succeed with ComboBox search part. It is still not clear for me **rewrite that part  to search in that index** . If possible could you provide with some code. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Marius Žilėnas:  1) index of words: `String[] data = new String[] {"English", "French", "Spanish", "Japanese", "Chinese"};    
        for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
        jComboBox1.addItem(data[i]);
        jComboBox1.setEditable(true);`                                                           2) `{if data.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(enteredText.toLowerCase())) {filterArray.add(data.get(i));`                                                                         I don't know I think I am in wrong way. I totally lost in search part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I refactored the given code. It can recognize by the fragment. So "American English" and "English" are recognized when you put "English".

You could use the FilterComboBox class in your program.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 * A class for filtered combo box.
 */
public class FilterComboBox
    extends JComboBox
{
    /**
     * Entries to the combobox list.
     */
    private List<String> entries;

    public List<String> getEntries()
    {
        return entries;
    }

    public FilterComboBox(List<String> entries)
    {
        super(entries.toArray());
        this.entries = entries  ;
        this.setEditable(true);

        final JTextField textfield =
            (JTextField) this.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

        /**
         * Listen for key presses.
         */
        textfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        /**
                         * On key press filter the list.
                         * If there is "text" entered in text field of this combo use that "text" for filtering.
                         */
                        comboFilter(textfield.getText());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Build a list of entries that match the given filter.
     */
    public void comboFilter(String enteredText)
    {
        List<String> entriesFiltered = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String entry : getEntries())
        {
            if (entry.toLowerCase().contains(enteredText.toLowerCase()))
            {
                entriesFiltered.add(entry);
            }
        }

        if (entriesFiltered.size() > 0)
        {
            this.setModel(
                    new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                        entriesFiltered.toArray()));
            this.setSelectedItem(enteredText);
            this.showPopup();
        }
        else
        {
            this.hidePopup();
        }
    }
}
```

See how FilterComboBox works in Demo program.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Demo
{
    public static void makeUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Your frame");
        /**
         * Put data to your filtered combobox.
         */
        FilterComboBox fcb = new FilterComboBox(
                Arrays.asList(
                    "",
                    "English", 
                    "French", 
                    "Spanish", 
                    "Japanese",
                    "Chinese",
                    "American English",
                    "Canada French"
                    ));
        /**
         * Set up the frame.
         */
        frame.getContentPane().add(fcb);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        makeUI();
    }
}
```

Another approach, where we make existing comboboxes to filtered comboboxes. It is somewhat "decoration".

"Decorator" class.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 * Makes given combobox editable and filterable.
 */ 
public class JComboBoxDecorator
{
    public static void decorate(final JComboBox jcb, boolean editable)
    {
        List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jcb.getItemCount(); i++)
        {
            entries.add((String)jcb.getItemAt(i));
        }

        decorate(jcb, editable, entries);
    }

    public static void decorate(final JComboBox jcb, boolean editable, final List<String> entries)
    {
        jcb.setEditable(editable);
        jcb.setModel(
                    new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                        entries.toArray()));

        final JTextField textField = (JTextField) jcb.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

        textField.addKeyListener(
            new KeyAdapter()
            {
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                        new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            { 
                                comboFilter(textField.getText(), jcb, entries);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                } 
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Build a list of entries that match the given filter.
     */
    private static void comboFilter(String enteredText, JComboBox jcb, List<String> entries)
    {
        List<String> entriesFiltered = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String entry : entries)
        {
            if (entry.toLowerCase().contains(enteredText.toLowerCase()))
            {
                entriesFiltered.add(entry);
            }
        }

        if (entriesFiltered.size() > 0)
        {
            jcb.setModel(
                    new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                        entriesFiltered.toArray()));
            jcb.setSelectedItem(enteredText);
            jcb.showPopup();
        }
        else
        {
            jcb.hidePopup();
        }
    }

}
```

Demonstration class.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Demo
{
    public static void makeUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demonstration");

        /**
         * List of values for comboboxes.
         */
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList( 
            "",
            "English", 
            "French", 
            "Spanish", 
            "Japanese",
            "Chinese",
            "American English",
            "Canada French"
        );

        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList( 
            "",
            "Anglais", 
            "Francais", 
            "Espagnol", 
            "Japonais",
            "Chinois",
            "Anglais americain",
            "Canada francais"
        );

        /**
         * Set up the frame.
         */
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);

        /**
         * Create ordinary comboboxes.
         * These comboboxes represent premade combobox'es. Later in the run-time we make some of them filtered.
         */
        JComboBox<String> jcb1 = new JComboBox<>(list.toArray(new String[0]));
        panel.add(jcb1);

        JComboBox<String> jcb2 = new JComboBox<>();
        panel.add(jcb2);

        JComboBox<String> jcb3 = new JComboBox<>(list2.toArray(new String[0]));
        panel.add(jcb3);

        /**
         * On the run-time we convert second and third combobox'es to filtered combobox'es.
         * The jcb1 combobox is left as it was.
         * For the first decorated combobox supply our entries.
         * For the other put entries from list2.
         */
        JComboBoxDecorator.decorate(jcb2, true, list); 
        JComboBoxDecorator.decorate(jcb3, true); 

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        makeUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the answer of @Marius Žilėnas is helpful for the question of in this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368856/jcombobox-filter-in-java-look-and-feel-independent]

Comment: I w'd like to ask can I use  FilterComboBox class for my `JComboBoxes` as  `jComboBox1.add(fcb);`  `jComboBox2.add(fcb);` ?

Comment: With `JComboBoxDecorator.decorate(jComboBox2, true)` call the `jComboBox2` becomes filtered. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for "Decorator" class. I truly appreciate your time and effort. Sorry if I bothered you. I could apply your code to my generated `JComboBoxes`. But another problem is `JComboBox` at first it shows empty list, then when I enter the text that moment appers items of `JComboBox`. I w'd like to ask how to update the items of `JComboBox` ?

Comment: I accepted your answer and give you +1 for your kindness and professionalism. (^~^)

Comment: Thank you :)! Good catch, if the combo is empty it should get the entries that where passed along with decorate method. I've updated the code in decorator `public static void decorate(final JComboBox jcb, boolean editable, final List<String> entries)
    {
        jcb.setEditable(editable);
        jcb.setModel(
                    new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                        entries.toArray()));`
If decorate(jcb, true, entries) is applied on jcombobox jcb, then this jcb is filled with entries.

Comment: You are **GREAT** person that I have ever known. THANK YOU VERY MUCH. If you need any help (of course I think not in Java :))  I will do my best. (^~^)

Comment: Thank you!:) The helping you is enough of a reward. :)

Answer (score 0):

When trying to execute,  I had encountered two problems:

- When pressing ( up, down, enter ) buttons on keyboard. I solved it by preventing them using `return` statement.
- The popupMenuWillBecomeInvisble() is fired every time you write in textfield.
  I solved it by adding `getKeyStat()` add this code in main frame inside `popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible`

Hope this helps!

```
   private voidjCombobox1popupMenuWillBecomeInvisble(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt){
         if(JComboBoxDecorator.getKeyStat().equals("enter")){
           //write yor code here
        }
        }
```

---

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Makes given combo box editable and filterable.
 */
public class JComboBoxDecorator {
    static String checkenter="";
    
    public static String getKeyStat(){
       return checkenter;
    }
    
    public static void decorate(final JComboBox jcb, boolean editable) {
        List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jcb.getItemCount(); i++) {
            entries.add((String) jcb.getItemAt(i));
        }

        decorate(jcb, editable, entries);
    }
    
    public static void decorate(final JComboBox jcb, boolean editable, final List<String> entries) {
        jcb.setEditable(editable);
        jcb.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(entries.toArray()));

        final JTextField textField = (JTextField) jcb.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

        textField.addKeyListener(
                new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                     if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                         checkenter = "enter";
                     }
                    }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                   if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                      // e.consume();
                       return ;                       
                   }  
                   else{ 
                       comboFilter(textField.getText(), jcb, entries);
                   }
                    
                });
                checkenter = "type";
            }
        }
        );
    }

    /**
     * Build a list of entries that match the given filter.
     */
    private static void comboFilter(String enteredText, JComboBox jcb, List<String> entries) {
        List<String> entriesFiltered = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String entry : entries) {
            if (entry.toLowerCase().contains(enteredText.toLowerCase())) {
                entriesFiltered.add(entry);
            }
        }

        if (entriesFiltered.size() > 0) {
            jcb.setModel(
                    new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                            entriesFiltered.toArray()));
            jcb.setSelectedItem(enteredText);
            jcb.showPopup();
            
        } else {
            jcb.hidePopup();
        }
    }

}
```