# remove extra blanks and specified rows from JComboBox list

Tags: java, swing, text-files, jcombobox

I am reading big data from text file by `jComboBox` using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368268/populating-jcombobox-with-a-text-file?lq=1).

Text file have about 100 columns and I am reading necessary column with this code:

*(substring(12, 13) related to - **"A, B, C, D, ..."**, substring(58, 96) related to - **"Some text"**)*

```
jComboBox1.addItem(str.substring(12, 13) + str.substring(58, 96));
```

[image]

And in output I am getting `jComboBox` with empty rows and empty space.
As shown in picture I don't need to read rows flagged with **"AAA"** (*in blue line*) and rows with **comment** (*in red line*).

I would like to ask is it possible to remove extra blanks and exclude rows flagged with "AAA"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The short answer is, yes. You have two choices, either filter out the content when you read the file or filter out the content when you add it to your combobox

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found this [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753375/jcombobox-search-list) and w'd like to adopt "Decorator" class, in that case can I include your method to "Decorator" class or necessary write separately filter classes?

Comment: The decorate you've describe simply wraps a preexisting combobox, so assuming you've filtered the list already, use you can use the decorator

Comment: @ MadProgrammer I used decorator class but in that case I am getting combo list with all columns (my purpose is read just 2 column). So it means if JComboBox is filterable in that case JComboBox doesn't support columns?

Comment: No, `JComboBox` doens't support columns, `JTable` does.  `JComboBox` is filterable by default, `JTable` is.  You need to parse you text, probably into a POJO and then use that, along with a custom `ListCellRenderer` to define how it should be shown in the `JComboBox`. In your case, filter the values you don't want out first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this answer :

```
for (String str : lines) {
   if ( (!str.startsWith("AAA")) && (!str.substring(12, 13).equals(" ")) )
      jComboBox1.addItem(str.substring(12, 13) + str.substring(58, 96));
}
```

Comment: Yes, also works. I'll edit my answer, I appreciate more your method.

Comment: @Normal design Thank you very much. Your code works very well. But I cannot decide, better use your code or method of  MadProgrammer?

Comment: I think that if you want to re-use the data from the file in another part of the code, it is better to apply my solution. Indeed, if the data has to be re-used, keep the original version of it instead of removing some of it from the beginning of the load.

Comment: @Normaldesign I w'd like to ask some advice from you, I want to make a filterable Combo list as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753375/jcombobox-search-list?lq=1). I tried to use `JComboBoxDecorator.decorate(jcb1, true, list);` but in that case in `ComboBox` I am again getting contents of text file with all columns. Is there any way to use "Decorator" class?

Comment: Have to do some research and work on it before answering you. I'll try to do it as fast as I can.