# AutoFilter JComboBox Data from Database on typing on the JComboBox

Tags: java, sql, swing, jcombobox, autofilter

I am trying to filter only valid values contained in the typed text of a JComboBox which is read from the database.
E.g From DB, i have 'Makindu', 'Mombasa'.
If i type 'a' both the 2 values should appear but if i type 'k' only Makindu should appear.

I have tried on typing on JComboBox event but it doesn't filter.
routecombo is the name of my jComboBox. I have tried the below code on jCombobox key type event but it doesn't work.

```
try {     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://SVR;databaseName=crmdb;user=sa;password=1234");
       stm=con.createStatement();
       result=stm.executeQuery("Select name from RouteMaster where name like '"+routecombo.getEditor().getItem()+"'");
       while(result.next()){
       routecombo.addItem(result.getString("name"));  
       }
       }catch (SQLException ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
       }
```

Am expecting the Combobox to show only filtered Names depending on what the user types.
Find attached an example of what am expecting to do.
[Expected FilterCombo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVkAA.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jcombobox filter in java - Look and feel independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368856/jcombobox-filter-in-java-look-and-feel-independent)

Comment: Kindly provide a working example as i have really tried and researched but none of the examples are working.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.